Proof of Chebyshev's association inequality
I am trying to understand the proof of Chebyshev's association inequality in the book Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence:

Theorem $2.14$ Let $f$ and $g$ be nondecreasing
real-valued functions defined on the real line. If $X$ is a real-valued
random variable, then
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{E}[f(X)]\boldsymbol{E}[g(X)]\leq \boldsymbol{E}[f(X)g(X)] .
\end{equation}

The proof is quite short: The trick is to consider a random variable $X'$ distributed as $X$ and independent of it. Then the inequality is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
0\leq\boldsymbol{E}[(f(X)-f(X'))(g(X)-g(X'))]
\end{equation}
and the authors say that the last inequality follows from the fact that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
0\leq(f(X)-f(X'))(g(X)-g(X'))
\end{equation}
if $f$ and $g$ are nondecreasing. Unfortunately I do not understand this, i.e. why does $(1)$ hold true? Are they implicitly assuming that $X'\leq X$?

If $X\leq X'$, then $f(X)\leq f(X')$ and $g(X) \leq g(X')$ since $f$ and $g$ are nondecreasing, hence$$ 0\leq(f(X)-f(X'))(g(X)-g(X')).$$
Analogously, if $X' \leq X$, then $f(X') \leq f(X)$ and $g(X') \leq g(X)$, hence $$ 0\leq(f(X)-f(X'))(g(X)-g(X')).$$
